# how to authorize your endpoint using oauth2

Tags: c#, .net-core, oauth-2.0, openiddict

I working on a dotnet project. there are 4 APIs. and one is identity server which Is implemented using openiddict. below you can see identity server project startup class

```
//startup.cs
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
         => Configuration = configuration;

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<MailSettings1>(Configuration.GetSection("MailSettings1"));
        services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, Services.MailService>();

        services.AddControllersWithViews();

        services.Configure<DataProtectionTokenProviderOptions>(o =>
                o.TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));

        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(o =>
        {
            o.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
            o.SlidingExpiration = true;
        });
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        {
              // Configure the context to use Microsoft SQL Server.
              options.UseNpgsql(
              Configuration.GetConnectionString("identitydb"),
                    opt =>
                    {
                        opt.EnableRetryOnFailure(
                            maxRetryCount: 10,
                            maxRetryDelay: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30),
                            errorCodesToAdd: new List<string>() { });

                        opt.UseAdminDatabase("postgres");
                    });

                options.UseOpenIddict();
            });

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
        {
             options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 4;
             options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
             options.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
             options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
             options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
             options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
             options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
        })
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.ClaimsIdentity.UserNameClaimType = Claims.Name;
            options.ClaimsIdentity.UserIdClaimType = Claims.Subject;
            options.ClaimsIdentity.RoleClaimType = Claims.Role;
            options.ClaimsIdentity.EmailClaimType = Claims.Email;
        });


        services.AddQuartz(options =>
        {
            options.UseMicrosoftDependencyInjectionJobFactory();
            options.UseSimpleTypeLoader();
            options.UseInMemoryStore();
        });

        services.AddQuartzHostedService(options => options.WaitForJobsToComplete = true);
        services.Configure<CookieTempDataProviderOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
        });

        services.AddSession();
        services.AddOpenIddict()

            // Register the OpenIddict core components.
            .AddCore(options =>
            {
              
                options.UseEntityFrameworkCore()
                           .UseDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>();

              
                options.UseQuartz();
            })

            // Register the OpenIddict server components.
            .AddServer(options =>
            {
                // Enable the authorization, device, logout, token, userinfo and verification endpoints.
                options.SetAuthorizationEndpointUris("/connect/authorize")
                           .SetDeviceEndpointUris("/connect/device")
                           .SetLogoutEndpointUris("/connect/logout")
                           .SetTokenEndpointUris("/connect/token")
                           .SetUserinfoEndpointUris("/connect/userinfo")
                           .SetVerificationEndpointUris("/connect/verify");

                // Note: this sample uses the code, device code, password and refresh token flows, but you
                // can enable the other flows if you need to support implicit or client credentials.
                options.AllowAuthorizationCodeFlow()
                           .AllowDeviceCodeFlow()
                           .AllowPasswordFlow()
                           .AllowRefreshTokenFlow();

                // Mark the "email", "profile", "roles" and "demo_api" scopes as supported scopes.
                options.RegisterScopes(Scopes.Email, Scopes.Profile, Scopes.Roles, "demo_api");

                // Register the signing and encryption credentials.
                options.AddDevelopmentEncryptionCertificate()
                           .AddDevelopmentSigningCertificate();

                // Force client applications to use Proof Key for Code Exchange (PKCE).
                options.RequireProofKeyForCodeExchange();

                // Register the ASP.NET Core host and configure the ASP.NET Core-specific options.
                options.UseAspNetCore()
                           .EnableStatusCodePagesIntegration()
                           .EnableAuthorizationEndpointPassthrough()
                           .EnableLogoutEndpointPassthrough()
                           .EnableTokenEndpointPassthrough()
                           .EnableUserinfoEndpointPassthrough()
                           .EnableVerificationEndpointPassthrough()
                           .DisableTransportSecurityRequirement(); // During development, you can disable the HTTPS requirement.

                // Note: if you don't want to specify a client_id when sending
                // a token or revocation request, uncomment the following line:
                //
                // options.AcceptAnonymousClients();

                // Note: if you want to process authorization and token requests
                // that specify non-registered scopes, uncomment the following line:
                //
                // options.DisableScopeValidation();

                // Note: if you don't want to use permissions, you can disable
                // permission enforcement by uncommenting the following lines:
                //
                // options.IgnoreEndpointPermissions()
                //        .IgnoreGrantTypePermissions()
                //        .IgnoreResponseTypePermissions()
                //        .IgnoreScopePermissions();

                // Note: when issuing access tokens used by third-party APIs
                // you don't own, you can disable access token encryption:
                //
                // options.DisableAccessTokenEncryption();
            })

            // Register the OpenIddict validation components.
            .AddValidation(options =>
            {
               
                options.AddAudiences("resource_server");

             
                options.UseLocalServer();


                options.UseAspNetCore();

            
            });

        // services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, AuthMessageSender>();
        services.AddTransient<ISmsSender, AuthMessageSender>();
        services.AddCustomDaprClient();

        // Register the worker responsible of seeding the database with the sample clients.
        // Note: in a real world application, this step should be part of a setup script.
        services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
        services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
        });

        services.AddCors();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/error");

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseCors(x => x
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => true) // allow any origin
                .AllowCredentials()); // allow credentials

        app.UseSession();

        app.UseRequestLocalization(options =>
        {
            options.AddSupportedCultures("en-US", "fr-FR");
            options.AddSupportedUICultures("en-US", "fr-FR");
            options.SetDefaultCulture("en-US");
        });

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(options => options.MapControllerRoute(
         name: "default",
         pattern: "{controller=Account}/{action=Register}/{id?}"));
    }
}
```

now I want use this identity server to protect other apis endpoint.

as example, let say I have a "booking" API. I want protect some endpoint. when send a request from UI it include a bearer token in the header (already implementd. used next js for UI framework). I need to validate  that access token and check if it's not expired.

```
[HttpGet("name")]
[Authorize]
public async Task<ActionResult<ResponseVM>> IsBooked(string name)
{
    return await _mediator.Send(new GetBookingDetailsByHotelNameQuery(name));
}
```

like above we can use Authorize tag to protect. can someone tell me how to check if the token is valide from this "booking" api using identity server

identiy server url - http://localhost:5001
we can get open id configuration from this url
"http://localhost:5001/.well-known/openid-configuration"

below you can see I added authentication middleaware to "booking" Api project

startup.cs

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                   .AddJwtBearer(options =>
                   {
                       options.Authority = "http://localhost:5003";
                       options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    
                       options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                       {
                           ValidateAudience = false
                       };
                   });
```

but I got this error

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler[3]
Exception occurred while processing message.
System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'System.String'.
at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
Connection id "0HMR7VA4R2D46", Request id "0HMR7VA4R2D46:00000003": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'System.String'.
at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.AuthenticateAsync()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.AuthenticateAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequests[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5005/api/Practice/uukuk - - - 500 0 - 12.5820ms
```

Comment: the discovery endpoint is `/.well-known/openid-configuration`

Comment: @ggeorge it's a typo fixed it. do you know how to do implement the authorization?

Comment: If i were you i would try to implement the bare minimum of identity server with the help of: https://github.com/DuendeSoftware/Samples/tree/main/IdentityServer/v6

Answer (score 0):

you can create custom middleware and use JWTSecurityTokenHandler Class. For ref https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.identitymodel.tokens.jwt.jwtsecuritytokenhandler?view=msal-web-dotnet-latest.

Code Reference:

`````
var token = httpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"].FirstOrDefault()?.Split(" ").Last();
                    var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
                    if (token != null && tokenHandler.CanReadToken(token))
                    {
                        var tokenPayload = tokenHandler.ReadJwtToken(token).Payload;
                        var issuer = tokenPayload.Iss;
                        var jsonKeyString = GetJsonKeyString(issuer);
                        tokenHandler.ValidateToken(token, new TokenValidationParameters
                        {
                            IssuerSigningKey = new JsonWebKey(jsonKeyString),
                            ValidateAudience = false,
                            ValidateIssuer = false,
                            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                            ValidateLifetime = Convert.ToBoolean(_configuration["JWT:validateLifetime"])
                        }, out SecurityToken validatedToken);

                        await _next(httpContext);````
`````

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi @Nitish I update my question could you please take a look